# How can I find the sum of the elements of an array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to add the elements of an array that is defined by user input from the `read -a` command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
read -a array
tot=0
for i in ${array[@]}; do
  let tot+=$i
done
echo "Total: $tot"
```

Comment: what is the function of "let"?

Comment: adds each item to the total.

Comment: can you do this using "expr"?

Comment: @BobbyT28, but you don't need to call out to an external program when the shell has the ability to do arithmetic.

Comment: Does `let` work with decimals? I had to use `total=$(echo "$total + $i" | bc -l)`

Answer (score 26):

Given an array (of integers), here's a funny way to add its elements (in bash):

```
sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${array[*]}))")
echo "Sum=$sum"
```

e.g.,

```
$ array=( 1337 -13 -666 -208 -408 )
$ sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${array[*]}))")
$ echo "$sum"
42
```

Pro: No loop, no subshell!

Con: Only works with integers

#### Edit (2012/12/26).

As this post got bumped up, I wanted to share with you another funny way, using `dc`, which is then not restricted to just integers:

```
$ dc <<< '[+]sa[z2!>az2!>b]sb1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1lbxp'
42
```

This wonderful line adds all the numbers. Neat, eh?

If your numbers are in an array `array`:

```
$ array=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 )
$ dc <<< '[+]sa[z2!>az2!>b]sb'"${array[*]}lbxp"
42
```

In fact there's a catch with negative numbers. The number '-42' should be given to `dc` as `_42`, so:

```
$ array=( -1.75 -2.75 -3.75 -4.75 -5.75 -6.75 -7.75 -8.75 )
$ dc <<< '[+]sa[z2!>az2!>b]sb'"${array[*]//-/_}lbxp"
-42.00
```

will do.

Pro: Works with floating points.

Con: Uses an external process (but there's no choice if you want to do non-integer arithmetic — but `dc` is probably the lightest for this task).

Comment: That went way over my head :-|

Comment: does not work on natural numbers: $ echo "${arrr[*]}"
2 1 34 3 2
$ IFS=+ read <<< "${arrr[*]}" then no + is provided: $ echo $REPLY
2 1 34 3 2

Comment: The (very smart) first solution does create a subshell because command substitution (`$(...)`) in Bash _always_ creates a subshell.  See [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338131/4154375) to [When does command substitution spawn more subshells than the same commands in isolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21331042/4154375).

Answer (score 9):

My code (which I actually utilize) is inspired by answer of [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635566/1300875). I personally consider this more clear to read/comprehend, and to modify. Accepts also floating points, not just integers.

Sum values in array:

```
arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )
IFS='+' sum=$(echo "scale=1;${arr[*]}"|bc)
echo $sum # 55
```

With small change, you can get the average of values:

```
arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )
IFS='+' avg=$(echo "scale=1;(${arr[*]})/${#arr[@]}"|bc)
echo $avg # 5.5
```

Comment: An ellegant, quick and even simple solution. Thanks you.

Comment: FYI this can have consequences in other parts of a script when IFS is defined

Comment: Yes, @MikeQ. The IFS must be moved inside the subshell to prevent contaminating the running shell. `arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ); echo $(IFS='+'; bc<<<"scale=1;(${arr[*]})/${#arr[@]}")` Also, you can use a "Here String" instead of echo to save 1 process.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, then one could backup and restore IFS variable after the operation etc. ..

Comment: @MikeQ The way IFS is (re-)defined here, it will only be in effect for that single command line. Backing up and restoring IFS is not necessary here

Answer (score 7):

gniourf_gniourf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635566/8271263) is excellent since it doesn't require a loop or bc. For anyone interested in a real-world example, here's a function that totals all of the CPU cores reading from /proc/cpuinfo without messing with IFS:

```
# Insert each processor core count integer into array
cpuarray=($(grep cores /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print $4}'))
# Read from the array and replace the delimiter with "+"
# also insert 0 on the end of the array so the syntax is correct and not ending on a "+"
read <<< "${cpuarray[@]/%/+}0"
# Add the integers together and assign output to $corecount variable
corecount="$((REPLY))"
# Echo total core count
echo "Total cores: $corecount"
```

I also found the arithmetic expansion works properly when calling the array from inside the double parentheses, removing the need for the read command:

```
cpuarray=($(grep cores /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print $4}'))
corecount="$((${cpuarray[@]/%/+}0))"
echo "Total cores: $corecount"
```

Generic:

```
array=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
sum="$((${array[@]/%/+}0))"
echo "Total: $sum"
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm a fan of brevity, so this is what I tend to use:

```
IFS="+";bc<<<"${array[*]}"
```

It essentially just lists the data of the array and passes it into BC which evaluates it. The "IFS" is the internal field separate, it essentially specifies how to separate arrays, and we said to separate them with plus signs, that means when we pass it into BC, it receives a list of numbers separated by plus signs, so naturally it adds them together.

Comment: Could you please expand on the `<<<` simbol?

Comment: echo ${nums[@]} | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc

Comment: so we dont f' with IFS

Answer (score 3):

Another `dc` & `bash` method:

```
arr=(1 3.88 7.1 -1)
dc -e "0 ${arr[*]/-/_} ${arr[*]/*/+} p"
```

Output:

```
10.98
```

The above runs the expression `0 1 3.88 7.1 _1 + + + + p` with `dc`.  Note the dummy value `0` because there's one too many `+`s, and also note the usual negative number prefix `-` must be changed to `_` in `dc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr=(1 2 3) //or use `read` to fill the array
echo Sum of array elements: $(( ${arr[@]/%/ +} 0))
Sum of array elements: 6
```

Explanation:

1. `"${arr[@]/%/ +}"` will return `1 + 2 + 3 +`
2. By adding additional zero at the end we will get `1 + 2 + 3 + 0`
3. By wrapping this string with BASH's math operation like this`$(( "${arr[@]/%/ +} 0"))`, it will return the sum instead

**This could be used for other math operations.**

1. For subtracting just use `-` instead
2. For multiplication use `*` and `1` instead of `0`

**Can be used with logic operators too.**

1. BOOL AND EXAMPLE - check if all items are true (1)

   `arr=(1 0 1)`

   `if [[ $((${arr[@]/%/ &} 1)) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`

   This will print: no
2. BOOL OR EXAMPLE - check if any item is true (1)

   `arr=(1 0 0)`

   `if [[ $((${arr[@]/%/ |} 0)) -eq 1 ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`

   This will print: yes

Answer (score 0):

I find this very simple using an increasing variable:

```
result2=0
for i  in ${lineCoffset[@]};
do
    result2=$((result2+i))  
done
echo $result2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way

```
function arraySum 
{
        sum=0
        for i in ${a[@]};
        do
              sum=`expr $sum + $i`  
        done
        echo $sum
}

a=(7 2 3 9)
echo -n "Sum is = " 
arraySum ${a[@]}
```